# Installed Postgres.app but it won't work

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql

I just installed [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) on my Mac but it won't work properly. I finished the installation and the app icon is on the menu bar and it says it is listening on port 5432, however, that is what happens if I try to run it from the command-line:

```
~ $ psql
zsh: correct 'psql' to 'sl' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: psql
```

I had previously installed PostgreSQL via Homebrew but removed it before installing Postgres.app. I am running Mac OS X Lion.

I appreciate any help, I really want to have PostgreSQL running on my machine.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `psql` binary for Postgres.app is inside the application bundle and you'll have to add the appropriate directory to your `PATH`. From the [fine manual](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html):

> **Configure your `$PATH`**
>
> Postgres.app includes many command line tools. If you want to use them, you must configure the `$PATH` variable.
>
> If you are using **bash** (default shell on OS X), add the following line to `~/.bash_profile`:
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
> ```
>
> [...]

So adjust your `PATH` setting in your zsh config files to include the

```
Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

directory inside your `Postgres.app` bundle.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it worked. I'm having a different trouble now tho ERROR:  invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "utc"

Comment: @rodrigoalvesvieira Post a new question with more detail on that if you need to.

Comment: Note that for the current version of Postgres.app the correct path to is "/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin"

Comment: should I add it to .bash_profile, or ZSH has some other own profile? If so, then where it is stored?

Comment: @andi: You'd add it where ever your `PATH` is defined and that depends on the shell you're using.

Comment: As for today the location of the bin directory is:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin

Comment: and today it's `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @micheleb

Answer (score 24):

I'm reading this as of April 2014 and the directory you must include in your path as far as my Postgres app is concerned is slightly different.

I had to include this:

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH"`

I can now run psql in my terminal.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  The first with `..Contents/MacOS/bin` did not.

Answer (score 6):

What you should do is to use /latest instead of version so you dont need to change it again when updating Postgres.

How to: http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

then run:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

to reload .bash_profile and update any functions you add.

Answer (score 6):

**On zsh shell** you have the modify `.zshrc`:

```
PSQL_PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$PSQL_PATH"
```

**On prompt**:

```
exec $SHELL
which psql
```

Answer (score 1):

This might seem stupid, but I'm curious where you installed Postgres.app? As was suggested in `mu is too short`'s answer, the documentation mentions adding `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` to your path. However, this requires that you have installed Postgres.app in your `/Applications/` folder.

Before trying any of the more complicated solutions you might have found on Stack Overflow, and other resources via Google, you should make sure you've installed Postgres.app to the right place. It may be as simple as moving Postgres.app to `/Applications/` since `psql` will be found in `/Applications/Postgres.app` before any other places.

Alternatively, you could use whatever path to Postgres.app you would like. So if you want it in your home directory, then you could use `export PATH="~/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`.

HTH

Comment: BTW, this answer is more or less for anyone who stumbles across this question going forward, since I assume the original author has already resolved their problem after 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a previous Ubuntu user, now in OSX Trying to run the "which sql" and "pg_restore" commands directly from a terminal I opened didn't work.  I clicked on the elephant icon and opened a terminal by "Open psql". Once I've quit from the psql console and written the commands in that terminal, they all worked.

Answer (score -1):

On ZSH terminal, before trying the above solutions you have to install Postgres in the first place. While using `Hombrew`
First, hit,

`brew install postgres` Then check if it is installed by   `which psql`

Comment: `Postgress.app` recommends removing any postgres installations that were installed via `brew`. This way there's no conflicting servers or services running, but then you lose out on the cli tooling. To be honest though I'm installing it back via brew so I can quickly access my tooling, but realize that I need to: Make sure the versions match up, make sure to determine which postgres I would like to be running as a service (brew's or postgressapp's).